# How are @"Strings" allocated in memory?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, memory-management

I am curious of the memory allocation for the following code.

```
NSString *myString = [NSString string];
```

I know this will create an autoreleased empty string, `@""`

What happens when I then call

```
myString = @"Hello world";
```

Is my reference the same as the autoreleased object `NSString` provided or did I just allocate a new object that I am responsible for releasing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When wondering whether you own an object, ask yourself:

Does the method I used to create this object...

- begin with `new`?
- begin with `alloc`?
- contain `copy`?
- equal `retain`?

If you can answer "Yes" to any of those, then you are responsible for invoking `release` or `autorelease` on the returned object.  (Note that the rules for Core Foundation objects are *slightly* different.  Also note that anything that the documentation explicitly says that contradicts this wins.  The documentation always supersedes the guidelines)

In the case of your string, the answers to all your questions are "no", so you are not responsible for the object.  Constant strings (of the style `@"foo"`) are hard-coded into the application binary and *cannot* be deallocated.  That, however, is an implementation detail.  As long as you follow the memory management rules, you'll be good!

Comment: Recently I have read a very nice article on memory management http://goo.gl/Tp8WW
Hope this help you to understand better.

Comment: Thanks, I am generally very comfortable with Cocoa memory management, I was just a little perplexed at how the hard coded strings work.

Comment: @Flash84x:  The implementation detail that prevents deallocation is that constant strings have a retain count of INT_MAX.  This is treated as a special case by the run time and turns `retain` and `release` into no-ops.