# Memory leak from static NSString

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, memory-management

I'm a first time Objective C programmer. I've been reading other people's code and I often see static strings created but never released. Take this for example:

```
- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView 
   cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
   static NSSSTring* foo = @"foo";
   // [code to return a cell for the table]
}
```

To my understanding, space for 3 characters in the heap has been allocated to store the string "foo". When the program terminates, those 3 characters are never reclaimed because the author never releases them. Isn't there a memory leak here? Why or why not?

Comment: Take a look at this questions I asked awhile back. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4436016/how-are-strings-allocated-in-memory

Comment: Just one note: When a program terminates, all memory allocated by the corresponding process is reclaimed by the operating system. There’s no such thing as memory leak upon termination regardless of objects being static strings or heap-allocated objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, constant strings like `@"foo"` are treated specially by the compiler. In particular, they are *not* heap allocated, and they do not participate in reference counting, i.e., they are never actually released; their memory is part of your program's image, just like the content of, say, `"foo"`. However, this should be treated as implementation detail of this particular kind of `NSString` subclass. Follow the usual rules for reference retention/release.